# How to show different dialog messages for different Permissions?

Tags: android, permissions, runtime

I have implemented runtime permission in my project mainly READ_PHONE_STATE,READ_CONTACTS,GET_ACCOUNTS. Let suppose user denies 2 out of 3 then i have to show single dialog messages about each denied permission.How do i do that

code:-

```
PermissionManager.with(this)
            .key(2100)
            .permission(PermissionEnum.READ_PHONE_STATE, PermissionEnum.READ_CONTACTS, PermissionEnum.GET_ACCOUNTS, PermissionEnum.READ_SMS, PermissionEnum.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PermissionEnum.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, PermissionEnum.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PermissionEnum.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .askAgain(true)
            .askAgainCallback(new AskAgainCallback() {
                /*Callback to handle denied permission response*/
                @Override
                public void showRequestPermission(UserResponse response) {
                    showDialog(response);
                }
            })
            .callback(new SmartCallback() {
                /* To handle the result of permissions after all successful/ unsuccessful user transactions*/
                @Override
                public void result(boolean allPermissionsGranted, boolean somePermissionsDeniedForever) {
                    if (allPermissionsGranted) {
                        init();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            })
            .ask();
```

to show dialog:-

```
private void showDialog(final AskAgainCallback.UserResponse response) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(Splash.this)
            .setTitle("Permission needed")
            .setMessage("This app really need to use these permissions, do you want to authorize it?")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    response.result(true);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("NOT NOW", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    response.result(false);
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .setCancelable(false)
            .show();
}
```

But need to show single message in dialog for each denied permission.

Comment: it seems like you are using library for managing permissions. You should ask the author of the lib as they will be able to help better.

Answer (score 0):

1. String Permissions array

```css
final String[] permisions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
```

2. Request Permissions

```js
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permisions, Permissions_Request_Code);
```

## 3 . @Override Method

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
```

4. InSide onRequestPermissionsResult you will get grantResults array

#### @Override

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) { // RequestCode for our Permissions
        case Permissions_Request_Code:
            if (grantResults.length != 0) { // Check Granted Results Not Null
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { // Permission Granted for Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

                    // DO What You Want
                } else// Permission Denied for Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                {
                    // Display Error Dialog
                }
                if (grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {// Permission Granted for Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                    // DO What You Want
                } else // Permission Denied for Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                {
                    // Display Error Dialog
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```